# How to keep new line character \n in list element?

Tags: python

I am currently solving Project Euler 59. I take given ASCII sequence and xor it with 3 letter converted ASCII key. When I xor it and 2 elements in a row by chance are `\` and `n` then my result becomes like that:

`\\n` instead of `\n`

As far as I understand it puts extra backslash to ignore new line, but I need my list exactly as it is for obvious reason. How can I have `\n` in my list without it becoming new line?

EDIT: now I double checked, everytime xor result becomes `\` , it changes to `\\` automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `'\\n'` you are seeing is actually a `'\n'`.  The `'\\'` is just the way a backslash is escaped in strings, and as Joran points out, is a single character.  For more information on escape sequences in Python strings, see https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals

```
>>> s = '\\n'
>>> print s
\n
>>> print repr(s)
'\\n'
```

Comment: So what you mean is if I do calculations or comparisons with element `.\\n` it will be exactly the same as if I did with element `.\n`?

Comment: No.  `.\\n` is a period followed by a backslash followed by the letter `n`.  `.\n` is a period followed by a newline.  The way to have a literal backslash in a string in Python is with `'\\'`.

Comment: What I meant, if I let's say convert `.\\n` to integer, will it be the same result as if I converted ASCII characters `.\n` to integer? Edit: going to check this myself.

Answer (score 0):

I think you misunderstand `"\\"` is one character:

```
print len("\\") 
print ord("\\")
```

Comment: How can it be 1 character? I calculated xor myself, and first 3 elements in the list should be `.\n` but they are `.\\n`

Comment: what is your 3 letter key thing ... it is indeed only one character as illustrated above...